scene.ray_cast gets hit on objects NOT in Local View
Using scene.ray_cast is returning a hit on objects that are "hidden" when in local view. My addon needs to highlight edges on mouseover, so this is particularly annoying if one selects an object and quickly isolates it using local view, then any object in front of it in the viewport gets the hit from the ray_cast, even though the object is no longer visible in the viewport.
Is this just a known limitation, or is there a way to have the ray pass through objects that are not in a list (created from the objects in local view)? Or am I missing something?
